# Is there somewhere I can find a list of just Rosh Chodesh for the year in Gregorian with one and two-day RC?

Tags: calendar

It would be convenient if I could find a list of RC for the year, such as

5781 2020/2021:

- Rosh Chodesh Sh'vat  1/14    Th
- Rosh Chodesh Adar    2/12-13 F S
- ...

But this is what I've found:

1. https://www.hebcal.com/holidays/#rosh-chodesh
   Has a nice list but I can't tell 1 or 2 day RC without clicking on that month.
2. http://jewishholidaysonline.com/2021
   Is complete with all holidays, but it's too long for me; I would just like a concise list of RC.

Yea I could take #2 and [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) it, or just copy from a visual calendar but this seems to me like a useful thing to have just ready.

Comment: If you have a list of rosh hashanah dates, you can easily back calculate all the intermediate rosh chodesh dates.

Comment: How?  I don't see in S"A, and haven't found a guide.  Is there an easy rule which RC are double and is there mnemonic?

Comment: Start with one Rosh Hashana and count backwards with alternating 29 and 30 day months (Elul 29, Av 30, Tammuz 29, etc.). If you get to the previous Rosh Hashana and find your self missing a day or with an extra day, go back and add in 30 Marcheshvan or remove 30 Kislev respectively and adjust the start dates of Marcheshvan/Kislev accordingly. Remember to stick in a 30 day Adar I when necessary. Easy enough in a few lines of code.